# Bukkit yaml checker

Tags: yaml, bukkit

Heres my code it says theres something wrong with one of the mapping values when I put it in the yaml checker.. Note: I took the addresses out as they are very confidential, it shouldn't affect anything.)

```
groups:
  md_5:
  - admin
disabled_commands:
- disabledcommandhere
player_limit: -1
stats: 34cce1fc-17ab-4156-bb9a-a1c06151137d
permissions:
  default:
  - bungeecord.command.server
  - bungeecord.command.list
  admin:
  - bungeecord.command.alert
  - bungeecord.command.end
  - bungeecord.command.ip
  - bungeecord.command.reload
listeners:
- max_players: -1
  fallback_server: hub
  host: 0.0.0.0:25577
  bind_local_address: true
  ping_passthrough: false
  tab_list: GLOBAL_PING
  default_server: hub
  forced_hosts: 
    pvp.md-5.net: pvp
  tab_size: 60
  force_default_server: false
  motd: '&1Another Bungee server'
  query_enabled: false
  query_port: 25577
timeout: 30000
connection_throttle: 4000
servers:
  Hub:
    address: 198.50.128.131:25565
    restricted: false
    motd: '&1&l>&d&l>&r&b&lWelcome to &6&l&NFooseNetwork&1&l<&d&L<'
ip_forward: false
online_mode: true
  Skyblock:
    address: 198.50.128.133:25565
    restricted: false
    motd: ''
ip_forward: false
online_mode: true 
  Factions:
    address: 198.50.128.143:25565
    motd: ''
ip_forward: false
online_mode: true
```

Comment: Try any online YAML checker, e.g.  [this one](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com). It provides descriptive error message in case of incorrect input.

Comment: It's not especially productive to make people guess what problem your having. If you're seeing an error message your question should include the exact text of the error message and, if it refers to a line number, a mention of which line in your question it corresponds to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
online_mode: true
  Skyblock:
    address: 198.50.128.133:25565
    restricted: false
    motd: ''
```

The mapping that begins with the `Skyblock` key is indented under the `online_mode` key, which would make it the value of that key, but that key already has the value `true`.

A few lines later you have a second `online_mode` key—duplicate keys are not allowed, although not all parsers are strict about this—and you repeat the same error as above with `Factions`.

I'm not certain, but I *think* what you want is something like this:

```
servers:
  Hub:
    address: 198.50.128.131:25565
    restricted: false
    motd: '&1&l>&d&l>&r&b&lWelcome to &6&l&NFooseNetwork&1&l<&d&L<'
    ip_forward: false
    online_mode: true
  Skyblock:
    address: 198.50.128.133:25565
    restricted: false
    motd: ''
    ip_forward: false
    online_mode: true 
  Factions:
    address: 198.50.128.143:25565
    motd: ''
    ip_forward: false
    online_mode: true
```

Here the value of the `servers` key is a mapping with three keys (`Hub`, `Skyblock` and `Factions`), each of whose values is in turn a mapping.